# Deleting from Many-to-Many relationships in EntityFramework 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am attempting to delete a series of entities using EntityFramework 4. Here is the code I am using:

```
var role = (
    from r in context.tblAdminRoles
    where r.AdminRoleId == this.Role.AdminRoleId
    select r
).First();

this.AdminUser.tblAdminRoles.Remove(role);
context.SaveChanges();

context.tblAdminRoles.Remove(role);
context.SaveChanges();
```

However, when I execute it, I get the following error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint `"FK_tblAdminUserRole_tblAdminRole"`. The conflict occurred in database `"MyMainSite2"`, table `"dbo.tblAdminUserRole"`, column `'AdminRoleId'`.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

My database has the following structure:

```
----------------      --------------------      ----------------
|              |      |                  |      |              |
| tblAdminUser | ---< | tblAdminUserRole | >--- | tblAdminRole |
|              |      |                  |      |              |
----------------      --------------------      ----------------
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction about what might be going wrong?

Comment: Remove the first context.SaveChanges();

Comment: Code First: I am not, no

Comment: sza: That doesn't seem to be it

Comment: Are you sure that there are not other references to the role? Looks like it is assigned to other users as well.

Comment: Gert: This code is inside a unit test sadly not. From the error it seems it is somehow because of tblAdminUserRole - as though the role were being deleted before the entry in that table

Comment: You should be able to diagnose that by setting a break point at the second-last line.

Comment: Why do you need the first AdminUser.tblAdminRoles.Remove(role), and then save, and then remove the role from the context?  remove those 2 lines, and just remove the role from the context, then save?  Removing it from the context, should automatically remove it from the User's collection

Comment: Are your fks backwards? Run profiler and verify the sql it outputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if *cascading delete* is enabled in the database for the two relationships refering to the link table `tblAdminUserRole`, especially for the `FK_tblAdminUserRole_tblAdminRole` to the `tblAdminRole` table. It looks like it isn't enabled, therefore deleting the role doesn't delete the entries in the link table which finally leads to the FK constraint violation.